# save the transient instance before flushing :

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I got an error at the time of working on spring boot hibernate project.
When I tried one to one mapping between user and shopping cart, it caused an error:

`save the transient instance before flushing : com.bookstore.domain.security.UserRole.role -> com.bookstore.domain.security.Role`

I tried using `cascade = CascadeType.All for @OneToOne mapping`, but it didn't work.

Comment: It typically happens when you save one entity that you linked with another unsaved one and you don't have a correctly configured cascade. If you could provide some code like the entity configuration and the method where you create and save the entities we could help more

Comment: can u please check the code? I am sending the link : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ywEZwTVZenhT6rBKMwt529lT-JxwddFh

Comment: you can just edit your question with a copy paste of the relevant part, its typically much more appreciated than a link to the files and it's faster for you too

Comment: the problem comes when I use @Transacational .  Is there any specific rule to use   it?